# When should I use a GET vs a link

Tags: html, http, http-headers

For a school project I am using a GET like a link, no parameters being sent, just to go to another page on my website, because the visual requirements we were given have it looking like a button and I didn't feel like styling an `<a>` tag like a button.

I'm aware that certain things with GET differ from using a link like that a GET cannot be opened in a new tab/window. I couldn't find anything though explaining when to use GET vs linking or if one is preferable to the other.

But since I'm not passing parameters, I'm wondering what really is the difference between using GET and `<a>` and if there is any reason why I should be using one over the other in this case?

Comment: The question is hard to understand. <a> is an HTML tag. GET is an HTTP method. Following a link on <a> normally causes a GET request.

So what's your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, when you use an "a" tag, if clicked, the browser sends a GET request behind the scenes.

You can use "a" tags, forms, or javascript to make a button / div link to another page (again, a GET request will be sent anyway) like this

```
<a href="http://example.com">
    <div class="btn btn-lg"> link </div>
</a>
```

Or:

```
 <form action="http://example.com">
    <input type="submit" value="link">
 </form>
```

**"a" links are preferable** to other methods since they are more descriptive regarding what is the element about, since they work in browsers that have JS disabled, and they are better for SEO purposes due to the fact that they are the "standard" way of linking pages.

Comment: This answer provides accurate information, however I am more concerned if there is a reason in my case why I should use `<a>` instead of GET. Is the only down side/reason to use `<a>` instead of GET that the user can't open it in a new tab/window?